# python - how do you store elements in a tuple

Tags: python, store, tuples

how to store elements in a tuple?

I did this:

```
for i in range (0, capacity):
    for elements in self.table[i]:
        # STORE THE ALL THE ELEMENTS IN THE TUPLE
```

Answer (score 7):

tuples are immutable. You can create a tuple. But you cannot store elements to an already created tuple. To create (or convert) your list of elements to a tuple. Just `tuple()` it.

```
t = tuple([1,2,3])
```

In your case it is

```
t = tuple(self.table[:capacity])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't told us - we can only guess what table looks like
If it is a list of lists for example, you can do this to get a tuple of tuples

```
>>> table =[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> tuple(map(tuple, table))
((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9))

>>> capacity=2
>>> tuple(map(tuple, table[:capacity]))
((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as `t = tuple(self.table[i])`

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want.

```
x = []
for i in range (0, capacity):
  for elements in self.table[i]:
    x.append(elements)
t = tuple(x)
```